# What can I do against a Key Error ' Csrftoken'?

Tags: python-3.x, github, keyerror, termux

I'm a complete beginner. I wanted to download something from github on Termux and everything went fine until the last step when the key error 'csrftoken' appeared. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out. That's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/alkrinsta/alkrinsta.py", line 146, in <module>
    sess = instabrute.Login(password)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/alkrinsta/alkrinsta.py", line 106, in Login
    sess.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken' : r.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']})
KeyError: 'csrftoken'
```

Comment: Print your `r.cookies.get_dict()` and inspect the keys. Probably it is called not `csrrftoken`, for example. Add this to your question.

Comment: I wrote r.cookies.get_dict() but how do I inspect the keys? And what exactly should I add to my question? Sorry if this is stupid but I have really no clue

Comment: Just `print(r.cookies.get_dict())` before line 106 of `alkrinsta.py` and show us the output of this

Comment: Where do I find this line?

Comment: Ough, sorry, I misread your question and thought that `alkrinsta` is your own code. It is not a `termux` problem, but external package problem. Here's a year old [issue](https://github.com/ALKR-HACKHECKZ/alkrinsta/issues/5). I'd advice to drop dependency of this unmaintained dead project of low quality and find some other solution (and be ethical, of course).

Comment: Ahh alright. Ok thanks tho

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.